# WPF - Implementing a listbox that allows the items to be moved up and down

Tags: .net, wpf, listbox

This is related to my last post.

i want to have up and down buttons on listbox items
so that they can moved up/down ie changed its index
in the list.

Any ideas how I would actualy do this?

Malcolm

Answer (score 3):

I would make a button that is an up button, and in its OnClick event, do something like:

```
int location = listItems.SelectedIndex;
if (location > 0)
{
    object rememberMe = listItems.SelectedItem;
    listItems.Items.RemoveAt(location);
    listItems.Items.Insert(location - 1, rememberMe);
    listItems.SelectedIndex = location - 1;
}
```

Keep in mind this isn't tested as I don't have visual studio open right now, but it should give you a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Use an ObservableCollection as a collection for your ListBox

ObservableCollection has a nifty [Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms654933.aspx) method which fires all the nice events goodness for your listbox to respond...

Answer (score 1):

I would include the order of the item in the model (ie. your data class). Then I'd bind the ListBox to a `CollectionView` that is sorted by that value. Your up/down buttons would then simply swap the value of this sort property in two of your data items.

Answer (score 1):

Move Up

```
int index = listbox.SelectedIndex;
if (index != -1)
{
    if (index > 0)
    {
        ListBoxItem lbi = (ListBoxItem)listbox.Items[index];
        listbox.Items.RemoveAt(index);
        index--;
        listbox.Items.Insert(index, lbi);
        listbox.SelectedIndex = index;
        listbox.ScrollIntoView(lbi);
    }
}
```

Move Down

```
int index = listbox.SelectedIndex;
if (index != -1)
{
    if (index < listbox.Items.Count - 1)
    {
        listboxlbi = (ListBoxItem)listbox.Items[index];
        listbox.Items.RemoveAt(index);
        index++;
        listbox.Items.Insert(index, lbi);
        listbox.SelectedIndex = index;
        listbox.ScrollIntoView(lbi);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can throw whatever you want into the ListBox. So you could just make your own control that has a label and two buttons for the arrows. Then throw it in the ListBox and attach the events.

Answer (score 0):

Are you binding it? Try to change the order of the item of the binding object and upadate the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding it:

```
private void MoveItemUp()
    {
        if (SelectedGroupField != null)
        {
            List<string> tempList = AvailableGroupField;
            string selectedItem = SelectedGroupField;

            int currentIndex = tempList.IndexOf(selectedItem);

            if (currentIndex > 0)
            {
                tempList.Remove(selectedItem);
                tempList.Insert(currentIndex - 1, selectedItem);
                AvailableGroupField = null;
                AvailableGroupField = tempList;
                SelectedGroupField = AvailableGroupField.Single(p => p == selectedItem);
            }
        }
    }

    private void MoveItemDown()
    {
        if (SelectedGroupField != null)
        {
            List<string> tempList = AvailableGroupField;
            string selectedItem = SelectedGroupField;

            int currentIndex = tempList.IndexOf(selectedItem);

            if (currentIndex < (tempList.Count - 1))
            {
                tempList.Remove(selectedItem);
                tempList.Insert(currentIndex + 1, selectedItem);
                AvailableGroupField = null;
                AvailableGroupField = tempList;
                SelectedGroupField = AvailableGroupField.Single(p => p == selectedItem);
            }
        }        
    }
```

I have not explained how to bind the command to a method assuming you would have already figured that out.